# Windowsのアイコン画像の変更/差し替え

Tags: windows

アイコンが`SHELL32.dll`内にあることを調べ、Visual Studioによりdllファイルが開けることを確認したのですが、このままWindowsのアイコンを変更することは可能ですか？
`SHELL32.dll`内の画像を差し替えたいのですがなにか参考になる文献はありますか？
例：マイコンピュータ

Comment: Shell32.dllのアイコンの置き換えでしか実現できないことなのでしょうか。質問に何のアイコンを変更したいのかなど目的を添えてみてはどうでしょう。代替手段があるかもしれません。

Comment: Shell32.dllのアイコンの置き換えが楽な方法かと思ったからです、作成が楽なのならば変更の意味で回答いただければと思いますが？

Comment: 目的がわからないので代案が出にくいのでは？と言っています。指定拡張子のアイコンを差し替えたいならツールがあります、デスクトップに出ているドキュメントフォルダのアイコンを変えたいならOSの標準機能でできます、特定フォルダの見た目を変更したい(ドキュメントフォルダなど)ならdesktop.ini編集という手があり、ただアイコンを作る上で既存のアイコンを元にしたかっただけならVisual Studio Image Libraryというアイコンなどのイメージ集(VS2010までは付属、VS2012、VS2013はダウンロード）があります。

Comment: **通常変更できないアイコン**、ゴミ箱、マイコンピュータ、シャットダウン、スタートボタン**が対象です**。Visual Studioで開けたということは何らかの変更が可能なのですよね？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- OSの機能やツールを利用した置き換え

OSのバージョンにも依るのですが、今手持ちは8.1なので8.1で話をすれば、

> ゴミ箱
>   マイコンピュータ

これはWindowsの標準機能で変更できます。

デスクトップを右クリック ＞ 個人設定

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

デスクトップアイコンの変更

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

で、アイコンを変えればアイコンは変更されます
（Explorerは一旦全部閉じて開き直す必要がありますが、Explorer上のアイコンも変わります。）

XP時代も画面のプロパティ ＞ デスクトップタブ ＞ デスクトップのカスタマイズから変更できたと思うので、Vistaも7もできる可能性は高いですね。
これで不足がなければこちらでどうでしょうか。

> スタートボタン

これはたしかアイコンじゃないです。
Windows 7だとexplorer.exeのビットマップリソースだった気がします。

仕掛けまでは調べていませんが、Windows7ならスタートボタンの画像を変更するツールはあったと思います。
その他 Windows 8.1では[Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/)を私は使っていますが、これにスタートボタンのアイコンを変更する機能がありますね。カスタムイメージも指定可能みたいです。

> シャットダウン

これはわからないです。XPの頃はLunaの画像を変更するツールを見かけたことがあるような…。

---

- exeやdllの書き換え

一般論として、WindowsのExeやDllのファイル構造は決まっているので、画像などのリソースがうめこまれている場所(.rsrcテーブル)を書き換えれば変更はできます。

http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

読みだすだけならWinAPIで LoadLibraryExあたりを使えばできたかと思います。

編集にあたってはすでに上がっているResoure Hackerなどのツールも存在します。しかしプログラム側がどういう読み込み方をしているのかは不明ですのでリソースを単純に差し替えただけでは動作しない場合もあります。（たとえばゲームなどは改造防止のためにいろいろチェックが盛り込まれている場合がありますね）

Shell32.dllなど（Win8だとImageRes.dllっぽいですが）システム関連のモジュールを書き換える場合、
そもそもOSがロード中で書き換えられない、OSが退避していたモジュールに書き戻される、Windows Updateのタイミングで書き換わる、ウィルススキャンが改竄と捉えるなどの可能性があります。  
他の回答でも上がっている通り、できるだけ避けた方がいいでしょう。  
ためしに書き換える場合は二度と起動しなくなることも覚悟しておいてください。

Comment: ゴミ箱、マイコンピュータが標準で変更できるのは勉強不足で知りませんでした。画像などのリソースがうめこまれている場所を書き換えれば変更はできます。が、二度と起動しなくなる可能性もということは、何度も実験し変更が反映されるようにしなければならないということですね。そうなるとツールを使うか実際に実験した人に聞くかしか無いわけですが、回答を総合的に見ると、セキュリティ上の都合で公開されていないと言うわけですね。Visual Studioがツールと同様の機能を持っていると勘違いしていたようです。

Answer (score 2):

SHELL32.dllはWindowsの重要ファイルであり、基本的に書き換えをすることはできません。
やりようによっては可能ですが、問題となる可能性もありますのでやめておきましょう。

Answer (score 2):

Resource Hackerなどのリソース編集ツールを使用すれば、書き換えできますが、
恐らくOSのシステムファイルの保護が働くため、不可能です。
それすら停止するという方法もありますが、セキュリティ上、とても危険です。